# Trouble with executing a bash with sudo privileges

Tags: bash, mount, sudo

I wrote a script that prompts me in dmenu the availible drives to mount or unmount and I added to the with `visudo` the following line

```
ALL ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/to/usb-mount
```

and the script basically takes decisions, and it executes one of this two lines

```
sudo mount $drive $target
sudo umount $drive
```

and I have a key binding that executes the command like

```
sudo /path/to/usb-mount
```

and well, It runs, it doesn't mount the drive, but if I run the script in the terminal, with `sudo`, runs the script and does mount.

Any Idea what I need to do?

Supposedly (to my understanding) If I run `sudo` all subsequent actions take `sudo` privileges.

Answer (score 3):

Read the messages logged by `sudo`, typically written to either `/var/log/secure` or `/var/log/auth.log` (depending on distribution) to see what is going on.

Some distributions enable the `requiretty` setting in their default `sudoers` file or have it as a compiled-in default in `sudo`. This adds an extra step to using `sudo` in a non-interactive context (i.e. where it cannot ask for passwords nor output messages to the user). Run `sudo -l` as your regular user account: the output will tell you if the `requiretty` setting is in effect for you.

To remove this restriction from your user account, if your username is e.g. `ekiim`, you can add

```
Defaults:ekiim !requiretty
```

to the `sudoers` file after any existing `Defaults` lines.